# Google Maps API not supporting IE 11

Tags: api, maps, internet-explorer-11

Our company has a program with IE 11 embedded into a tab in a program window. The notice we got was that the Maps API will not work with IE 11 any longer sometime in Feb). This software was partially custom written to fit our needs.

The software that we purchased was sold to another company that no longer wishes to update or support the software, but refuses to release it to allow for us to have it fixed. What option do we have here? There is a spot in the software to copy and paste the Google API key.

I'm not a programmer so I am clueless as to what steps to take next.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can also temporarily delay the degradation of the maps by specifying an available JavaScript API version that still supports IE11, i.e. `version 3.47` or lower. But after August 2022, IE11 support is effectively discontinued across all available Maps JavaScript API versions and channels.

The official recommendation for this is to **encourage your users to switch to a [supported browser](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport)**. For more details, you could refer to this [official explanation](https://groups.google.com/g/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/c/l3mdkZ5JyDg) of this question.

Comment: Sadly the program has IE 11 embedded into it using webcontrol. It would be nice to replace it with WebView2. The current owner/developer of the software has refused to do any further updates. So when the software breaks, they will lose customers on this older platform. Their newer software is only about half of what the older version is capable.

Comment: Well, this is really bad. As far as I know, IE support will end in June 2022, so after that, if there are any related issues in IE11, I think it may not be resolved in time or related support. I think this is the reason for switching to a supported browser.

Comment: I has ended already!! We lost our GOOGLE MAPS API access this week... and cannot find a workaround (internal Eclipse SWT Browser!)

Comment: This is what I hate about big tech. They have no reason to stop supporting IE except to force people to stop using it for their own selfish interests. It should be up to the user to decide which browsers are too old to bother with, not the API. A lot of those old browsers are still in the wild out there on mobile devices and old versions of Windows. It's completely reasonable and feasible to continue supporting them.