# Google Maps JS API v3 Notify‏ - Google Maps Platform support for Internet Explorer 11 will end in August 2022

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-11

Us there any version of google maps that will be working on IE11 after Aug 2022?

On Aug 2022 - What my customer will see on my website using IE11? An error message? Blank screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API not supporting IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427597/google-maps-api-not-supporting-ie-11)

Answer (score 0):

Just like what says in [this article](https://groups.google.com/g/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/c/l3mdkZ5JyDg):

> After August 2022 (when Maps JavaScript API version 3.47 is retired)
>
> IE11 support is effectively discontinued across all available Maps JavaScript API versions and channels.

So there's no version of Google Maps will support IE11 after August 2022. I think the maps will not load in IE11 at that time.

Comment: Thanks, what I'm trying to understand is what wull be the customer experience on IE11. Blank screen? Warning message, etc...

Comment: @Derix The maps will not load in IE11, so I think it will be blank screen in IE11.